# Auth issue in Powershell after password change

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-powershell

After a recent password change, I've been unable to perform "terraform plan" operations (or anything else that requires authentication to our Azure subscriptions. I actually suspect that this is more-properly an Azure AD issue, but decided to ask in the Terraform area first on the off chance someone else has encountered this (Googled multiple variations, but nothing definitive for the Powershell case)

The error message is:

```
│ Error: building account: getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-09-20T19:11:35.3441875Z' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2021-10-11T21:32:17.0000000Z'.
│ Trace ID: <GUID>
│ Correlation ID: <GUID>
│ Timestamp: 2021-10-11 23:41:09Z
│ To re-authenticate, please run:
│ az login --scope https://graph.windows.net//.default
│
│ with module.policyset_definitions.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│ on modules\policyset-definitions\main.tf line 1, in provider "azurerm":
│ 1: provider "azurerm" {
```

The Trace, Correlation, and Timestamps vary, of course, by attempt.

I've attempted:

```
Clear-AzContext
Clear-AzDefault
exit Powershell
```

(even rebooted, since this has occurred over several days now and I shut down after work) then log in again.

I've also tried:

```
$c = Get-AzContext
Remove-AzContext -InputObject $c
```

The closest Powershell equivalent to Azure Shell "az login --scope [https://graph.windows.net//.default"](https://graph.windows.net//.default%22) appears to be:

```
Connect-AzAccount -AuthScope https://management.azure.com/
```

That didn't change anything about the error- still occurs, still reports same time that the token was last issued.

Since the problem appears to be with my token and the grants associated with it, I decided to attempt to force a refresh of the grants by doing:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "<AzureADEmailAccount>"
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId <GUID>
```

The results are one of the reasons I suspect this is an AAD problem, not Terraform; the error message didn't change, but the time reported in "grant was issued on" changed from the time I changed my password to the time I ran Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken.

Any suggestions? I'm also going to try to reach out to Microsoft, but wanted to start here for a publicly-available answer.

Comment: Hello , could you please add the providers details you are using and also may I know the link to module that you are calling in script ?

Comment: Can you please try `Disconnect-AzAccount` , then close the powershell and reopen and run `Connect-AzAccount` , so that it clears the context and credentials all saved

Comment: I'm fairly certain I had already tried the Disconnect-AzAccount and Connect-AzAccount from Powershell before asking this question. Sorry I didn't include that in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get the Token refreshed from Powershell.

At the suggestion of MS Support, I installed the Azure CLI (had to beg hard to get the admin permissions to do so, that's the reason I hadn't tried that previously) so I could do the following:

```
az login --use-device-code
```

That resolved the issue.